# How to take input as integers into a list which is seperated by space in python?

Tags: python

I tried using below code but list contains integers as characters

```
>>>a=input().split()
2 3 4
>>>print(a)
['2','3','4']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> a=list(map(int,input().split()))
1 2 3
>>> print(a)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Try using this code.
Here map() function is used,which returns a map object and we can use list to store the input in a list

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

Output for `1 2 3`:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```